# Sending a message in a specific channel on Discord

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I've read multiple other threads on this, and every other one says to use either client.channels.get(id).send(msg) or client.channels.find(id).send(msg). However whenever I use either of those, this error message pops up:

> TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function
>
> > at ClientRequest. (C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Crow Bot\index.js:19:25)
> >
> > at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
> >
> > at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:311:20)
> >
> > at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:603:27)
> >
> > at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
> >
> > at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:476:22)
> >
> > at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
> >
> > at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
> >
> > at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
> >
> > at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)

My code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const fullUrl = 'https://jaiminisbox.com/reader/read/solo-leveling/en/0/'
var chapter = 1
const https = require('https')

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
  UrlExists(fullUrl);
})

function UrlExists(url) {
  //Infinite loop
    url = fullUrl
    url += chapter
    https.get(url, res => {
      if (res.statusCode != 404) {
        console.log('Chapter ' + chapter + ' exists')
        chapter += 1
        client.channels.get("id").send("Chapter exists")
      }
    })
    //Pause code to check every 5 minutes
}
```

Any other tips or advice would also be appreciated

**EDIT:**

The purpose of this bot is to check the website to see if the next chapter of the manga has been posted. If it leads to a 404, nothing happens, but if it doesn't then it will post the new chapter in a specific channel on Discord then will update the chapter it's checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
client.channels.cache.get("id").send("Chapter Exists")
```

Also you might want to refer to
[the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels)

[this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-certain-channel) might also be of use for you